# How to use local storage in JS to-do list?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on my JavaScript to-do list project and wanted to add local storage to my code, so I looked into some of the posts on StackOverflow and other documentation and implemented it using storage.setItem & storage.getItem to my code, how to implement local storage function to to-do list?

The code that I implemented didn't save any data/retrieve any data.
Could you check my localStorage code if they are the correct ones, please?

I'd like to add a newly added list item to the local storage, retrieve it when refreshing or reopening the browser, and delete it when I click the delete button.

```
let input = document.querySelector('#todo')
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let list = document.querySelector('#list');
let savedTasks = localStorage.getItem('tasks');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let txt = input.value;
  if (txt === "") {
    alert('Please write something to do!');
  } else {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = txt;
    list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", "todos");
    input.value = '';
    const delBtn = document.createElement("i");
    delBtn.classList.add("fas", "fa-trash-alt");
    li.appendChild(delBtn);
    delBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
      li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
      localStorage.removeItem("tasks");
    })
  }
})

list.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'LI') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
})
```

HTML

```
 <div class="todoList">
      <h1>To-do List</h1>
      <div class="add-element">
        <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Add new to-do">
        <button id="btn">Add</button>
      </div>
      <div class="element-list">
        <ul id="list"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yup that's correct but for retrieving on page load/refresh you need to create a eventListener for that

Comment: So you will need to append your items to an array and add and remove items from the array. When page loads you have to write out the items from the array.

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to store the string "todos" rather than an array or object you may be trying to make. Make sure your todo entries are getting store in an array or object and you'll want to update your call to localstore to `localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(todos));` since you can only store strings in localStorage. To retrieve it you would call `var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem("tasks"));` assuming in both cases your array is called todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage works with strings only, so you will need to convert the list to a string and back. That's usually done using JSON.

I've played around with your code a bit, here're a working sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-waterfall-69zui?file=/src/index.js

Assuming you have a function to take a to-do text and show it on the UI:

```
function addUIItem(txt) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = txt;
  list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
  const delBtn = document.createElement("button");
  delBtn.textContent = "x"; // a button needs some text, a  simple  "x" should do for a "Delete button"
  delBtn.classList.add("fas", "fa-trash-alt");
  li.appendChild(delBtn);
  delBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li); // remove from the UI
    savedTasks = savedTasks.filter((e) => e !== txt); // remove the in-memory element
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(savedTasks)); // store the new list in localStorage
  });  
}
```

In order to restore the tasks on page refresh, you can read the data from localStorage like this:

```
// read previous tasks. If no tasks were found, start with an empty list
let savedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) || [];
// add UI elements for any saved task
savedTasks.forEach(addUIItem);
```

Hope that helps :)

Thank you @FZs for your suggestion.